# paprefs missing folder

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, airplay

Recently I bought airport express. I can stream music to it with no problem at all, but just from MacBook or iPad. I found paprefs, which seemed to be the best choice for Ubuntu, but after installing them, all the options got greyed out. I read further that Ubuntu 20.04 creates folder with wrong name, so I ran this command `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/ /usr/lib/pulse-13.99` and nothing changed. I entered `/usr/lib` directory and found two useless shortcuts with names `pulse-13.99` and `pulse-13.99.1`. I've been trying to restore this folder by reinstalling paprefs, but it didn't help. Does anybody know what package does this folder belong to, and will simple reinstall recreate it? If not, is there any other way for this folder to come back?

Comment: *so I ran this command sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/ /usr/lib/pulse-13.99 and nothing changed* - option `Make discoverable PulseAudio network sound devices available locally` is enabled ?

Comment: `dpkg -S /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/` will show it.

Comment: the options are greyed out. `dpkg -S /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/` shows `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/`

Comment: Something off should be pulseaudio. At least on my System.